# How to submit a form with Mechanize in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, mechanize

When I run this code:

```
require 'mechanize'
require 'logger'
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'

agent = Mechanize.new
agent.log = Logger.new "mech.log"
agent.user_agent_alias = 'Mac Safari'
agent.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE
page = agent.get('https://sarathi.nic.in:8443/nrportal/sarathi/HomePage.jsp')
page = agent.page.links.find{|i| i.text == "Status of Licence"}.click
page.form(:name=>"dlform").field_with(:name=>"dlform:DLNumber").value="TN4020120005045"
page.submit
```

I get this error:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `submit' for #<Mechanize::Page:0x8e644cc>
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: You probably want to submit the form, not the page.

Comment: just chain the submit with the previous line as page.form(:name=>"dlform").field_with(:name=>"dlform:DLNumber").value="TN4020120005045".submit

Comment: @Sam that would invoke `"TN4020120‌​005045".submit`

Comment: @Stefan: My bad, haven't touched mechanize for a while now. Could you then break it into separate calls as form = page.form(:name=>"dlform"); form.field_with(:name=>"dlform:DLNumber").value="TN4020120‌​005045"; form.submit ?

Comment: @Sam that looks good, although I don't have Mechanize installed to test it. Maybe you should post that as an answer?

Answer (score 2):

@sudhagar, you should submit the `form` rather than the `page`. Also break it into separate calls for a cleaner code, as:

```
...
form = page.form(:name=>"dlform")
form.field_with(:name=>"dlform:DLNumber").value="TN4020120‌​005045"
form.submit 
...
```